# Issues in C with brackets on if condition

Tags: c, output

```
    #include<stdio.h>
 
void TOH(int,char,char,char);
 int n;
void main()
{
    printf("How many plates?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    TOH(n,'A','B','C');
}

if (n==1)
    printf("A -> B \n");

if (n==2) { 
    printf("A->C \n");
    printf("A->B \n");
    printf("C->B \n");
    }

 
void TOH(int n,char x,char y,char z)
{
    if(n>2)
    {
        TOH(n-1,x,z,y);
        printf("\n%c -> %c",x,y);
        TOH(n-1,z,y,x);
    }
}
```

I have output errors:

```
turnuri.c:12:1: error: expected identifier or '('
if (n==1)
^
turnuri.c:15:1: error: expected identifier or '('
if (n==2) { 
^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

Why? Thank you

Comment: Logically, when do you expect those if's to execute??

Answer (score 5):

`if` statements can only be used inside function bodies. Code should be like this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
 
void TOH(int,char,char,char);
int n;
void main() {
    printf("How many plates ?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    TOH(n, 'A', 'B', 'C');

    if (n == 1) {
        printf("A -> B \n");
    }
    
    if (n == 2) { 
         printf("A -> C \n");
         printf("A -> B \n");
         printf("C -> B \n");
    }
}
 
void TOH(int n, char x, char y, char z)
{
    if (n > 2) {
        TOH(n - 1, x, z, y);
        printf("\n%c -> %c", x, y);
        TOH(n - 1, z, y, x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `if`-statement appear outside of the `main()` function rather than within it.

This should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void TOH(int,char,char,char);
int n;
void main() {
    printf("How many plates ?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    TOH(n, 'A', 'B', 'C');

    if (n == 1)
    {
        printf("A -> B \n");
    }
    
    if (n == 2) 
    { 
         printf("A -> C \n");
         printf("A -> B \n");
         printf("C -> B \n");
    }
}
 
void TOH(int n, char x, char y, char z)
{
    if (n > 2) {
        TOH(n - 1, x, z, y);
        printf("\n%c -> %c", x, y);
        TOH(n - 1, z, y, x);
    }
}
```